# onchange not working jquery.selectbox

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins

In onchange event is not working in jquery.selectbox-05, i am using two dropdown box one for country another one state if i select the country the state will pickup automatically it's work in normal php dropdown but i use this code in jquery.selectbox it's not working anybody will help me

Here my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.selectbox-0.5.js"></script>
<script type= "text/javascript" src = "scripts/countries2.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selectBoxMedium').selectboxMedium();
    $('.selectBoxSmall').selectboxSmall();
    $('.selectBoxSmallest').selectboxSmallest();
    $('.selectBox').selectbox();
    $(document).pngFix(); 
});
<p class="formInput formSelectBox">
    <select onchange="print_state1('state',this.selectedIndex);" id="country" class= "selectBox data" name ="country"></select>
</p>

<p class="formInput formSelectBox">
    <select name ="state" id ="state" class="selectBox"></select>
    <script language="javascript">print_country1("country");</script>
</p>
```

Javascript functions:

```
function print_country1(country_id) {
    // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
    var option_str = document.getElementById(country_id);
    var x, i=0;
    for(x in country_arr){
        option_str.options[i++] = new Option(country_arr[x],country_arr[x]);
    }
}

function print_state1(state_id, state_index) {
    var option_str = document.getElementById(state_id);
    var x, i=0;
    state_index++;
    var state_arr = s_a[state_index].split("|");
    for(x in state_arr) {
        option_str.options[i++] = new Option(state_arr[x],state_arr[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the code? Paste your code (HTML and JavaScript) :D

Comment: paste the code for functions `print_state1` and `print_country1`? Function `print_country1` is correctly executed?

Comment: function print_country1(country_id){
 // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
 var option_str = document.getElementById(country_id);
 var x, i=0;
 for(x in country_arr){
  option_str.options[i++] = new Option(country_arr[x],country_arr[x]);
 }
}

function print_state1(state_id, state_index){
 var option_str = document.getElementById(state_id);
 var x, i=0; state_index++;
 var state_arr = s_a[state_index].split("|");
 for(x in state_arr){
            option_str.options[i++] = new Option(state_arr[x],state_arr[x]);
 }
}

Comment: i get code from this site http://bdhacker.wordpress.com/2009/11/21/adding-dropdown-country-state-list-dynamically-into-your-html-form-by-javascript/

Comment: @vicky, where u got the selectbox plugin?

Comment: I got from https://gist.github.com/1153573

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem... this plugin don't handle with dynamic options. I mean, when you do `$element.selectbox()` the plugin executes with the actual options for the select element and will not update the selectbox if you changes the options.

So, if you have a select element with **no options** and run the `selectbox` plugin, it will create a selectbox with no options elements. When you changes the country and do a "reload" in the options for `select#states`, all the states for the selected country are loaded and added as options for `select#states` element, but the plugin `selectbox` was executed in page load and will not reload the options in their elements :(

How to fix it? In your case, you should be able to remove the siblings of `select#state` (generated by selectbox plugin), update the options with new state values and then run again the selectbox plugin :)

Check this functional [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uhQRZ/) :)

PS: this fiddle is working with [countries-3.1.js](http://ufpr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/countries/Latest%20Version/countries-3.1.zip), the [jquery.selectbox-0.5](https://gist.github.com/1153573) and no CSS

Comment: thank you very much it's working fine but the js is implement in same page, once again thank you very much

Comment: @vicky I've added the JS in the same page because I couldn't find a direct link to .js file, only for some zip and the jsfiddle don't allow that I upload a new js file :\ For your case, you should still call the js script from remote file and do the JS manipulate that depends of DOM into $.ready :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this plugin is it cannot handle the onchange() event because of that we are mostly irritate. So, here is the solution for that..

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="jquery.selectbox-0.5.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.items').selectbox();
                $('#country_input').blur(function(){
                   setTimeout(function(){
                       var e = document.getElementById("country");
                       var countryCode = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
                       getState('state',countryCode);
                   },500)                        

                });
});

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getState(state_id, countryCode)
{
var option_str = document.getElementById(state_id);
option_str.length=0;
option_str.options[0] = new Option('Select State','');
option_str.selectedIndex = 0;
//write your code to get state list with the use of "countryCode"
var state_arr = stateListArray; //assume "stateListArray" is an array which is holding list of states
for (var i=0; i<state_arr.length; i++) {
    option_str.options[option_str.length] = new Option(state_arr[i],state_arr[i]);
}
$('#state').parent().children(':not(#state)').remove();
$('#state').selectbox();
}
</script>

<p>
<select id="country" class= "items" name ="country">
<option value="countryCode">Country Name</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.selectbox-0.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "scripts/countries2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selectBoxMedium').selectboxMedium();
    $('.selectBoxSmall').selectboxSmall();
    $('.selectBoxSmallest').selectboxSmallest();
    $('.selectBox').selectbox();
    $(document).pngFix();

    $('.selectBoxMedium, .selectBoxSmall, .selectBoxSmallest, .selectBox').change(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('class') + ' has changed');
    });

    $('#country').change(function() {
        print_state1('state', $(this+':selected').index());
    });

    print_country1("country");
});
</script>
<p class="formInput formSelectBox">
    <select id="country" class="selectBox data" name="country"></select>
</p>

<p class="formInput formSelectBox">
    <select name="state" id="state" class="selectBox"></select>
</p>
```

WHAT NOW?

Comment: Thank u for your reply, I have one doubt in this code in this page loading the <select onchange="print_state1('state',this.selectedIndex);" id="country" class= "selectBox data" name ="country"></select> called then only get the country but ur code is  
$('#country').change(function() {
 print_state1('state', $(this).val());
});
it's not load any country

Comment: i get code from this site http://bdhacker.wordpress.com/2009/11/21/adding-dropdown-country-state-list-dynamically-into-your-html-form-by-javascript/